# How to read/write from existing TAP interface in C

Tags: c, linux, networking

I have an existing tap device (`tap0`) that I created on command line.

```
# ip tuntap add dev tap0 mode tap
```

I want to read any data coming in on that interface using a C program. I checked other SO questions, but found code that create an interface by opening `/dev/net/tun`.

Can anyone provide some direction on how to open and read existing interface ? I'm not sure which file I should open for `tap0` ?

Comment: Could you find a tutorial on accessing existing devices before creating one yourself?

Comment: In the actual test, someone else would have created the interface for me. So I need to be able to open and read the interface just by knowing the name.

Comment: You could still use a tutorial on accessing existing devices. But what you wrote deserves being added to the question by [edit]ing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open the existing tun/tap interface similar way than creating a new one.
Just give name for the interface when ioctl(TUNSETIFF) is used:

```
const int fd = open("/dev/net/tun", O_RDWR);
if (fd != -1)
{
    struct ifreq ifr;

    memset(&ifr, 0, sizeof(ifr));
    ifr.ifr_flags = IFF_TUN | IFF_NO_PI;

    strncpy(ifr.ifr_name, "tun0", IFNAMSIZ);  // <<<<=== THIS WAY

    if (ioctl(fd, TUNSETIFF, &ifr) != -1)
    {
```

Without the `strncpy` line, the code creates a new interface with some free number. 
With the line, it tries to open tun0. Note: it fails if the tun0 is already opened by some other process.

Above is tested with IFF_TUN. I haven't tried IFF_TAP.

You can use the file descriptor `(fd)` for reading and writing:

Example for tun:

```
char buffer[0x1000];

const int len = read(fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
if (len > 0)
{
    static const char IPV6_VER_MASK = 0x60;

    if ((buffer[0] & IPV6_VER_MASK) == IPV6_VER_MASK)
    {
        handle_ipv6_packet((const struct ip6_hdr*)buffer, len);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can implement like a tcpdump to capture packets, can use libpcap or 
use socket RAW_SOCKET

```
sock = socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETH_P_ALL)
```

Of course you can also add the bpf filter

```
setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ATTACH_FILTER, ...
```

simple sample:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <netinet/ether.h>
#include <linux/if_packet.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int n;
    int ret = 0;
    int sock;
    char buf[2048];
    struct ifreq ifreq;
    struct sockaddr_ll saddr;

    // create socket
    if((sock = socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETH_P_ALL))) == -1) {
        ret = errno;
        goto error_exit;
    }

    // bind tap0
    snprintf(ifreq.ifr_name, sizeof(ifreq.ifr_name), "tap0");
    if (ioctl(sock, SIOCGIFINDEX, &ifreq)) {
        ret = errno;
        goto error_exit;
    }

    memset(&saddr, 0, sizeof(saddr));
    saddr.sll_family = AF_PACKET;
    saddr.sll_protocol = htons(ETH_P_ALL);
    saddr.sll_ifindex = ifreq.ifr_ifindex;
    saddr.sll_pkttype = PACKET_HOST;

    if(bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&saddr, sizeof(saddr)) == -1) {
        ret = errno;
        goto error_exit;
    }

    // recv data
    while(1) {
        n = recvfrom(sock, buf, sizeof(buf), 0, NULL, NULL);
        printf("%d bytes recieved\n", n);
    }

error_exit:
    if (ret) {
        printf("error: %s (%d)\n", strerror(ret), ret);
    }
    close(sock);
    return ret;
}
```